# Why we can't create object of another class as an element in php

Tags: php

I seen some of the answers of the same questions in the forum.. but still the answers are not providing a clear idea..

In other languages like C# is executing fine. but why not PHP?

Check the example:

```
class Student
{
    public $name;
    public $age;
    private $number;
}

class ss
{
    public $obj;
    public $objs=new Student();     //generating error

    public function act()
    {
        $obj = new Student();
        $obj->study();
        $obj->studentinfo();
    }
}

$ob = new ss();
$ob->act();
```

Comment: check my answer and let me know if i am lagging somewhere

Answer (score 1):

As per the PHP docs, any property values must be of a constant value.

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this
>   initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to
>   be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time
>   information in order to be evaluated.

If you want `$objs` to be a new instance of `Student`, you should initailise it in your constructor:

```
public function __constructor()
{
    $this->objs = new Student();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
class Student
{
    public $name;
    public $age;
    private $number;
}
class ss
{
    var $obj;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->obj = new Student();
        $this->obj->study();
        $this->obj->studentinfo();
    }
}

$ob=new ss();
$ob->act();
```